# How to create custom reports in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, reports, custom-reports

Now the real question 
I need to create custom reports based on conditions.

1. **Sales Report**
2. **Marketing Report**
3. **Customer Report**
4. **Product Report**

.  Example:

**Conditions:**

1. How  many products or list of products which sold more than 200 times.
2. I need to show it graphically in Charts (comparision,pie) e.g https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/

I have already develop extension how can I use google charts ?

Answer (score 1):

raw sql to get all product ids which were sold more than 200 times:

```
SELECT e.entity_id FROM magento2test.catalog_product_entity as e INNER JOIN magento2test.sales_order_item as soi 
ON e.entity_id = soi.product_id GROUP BY e.entity_id HAVING COUNT(soi.product_id) > 200;
```

Magento code to add needed changes to the product collection's select:

```
$reportCountVal = 200;
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->getSelect()
     ->joinLeft(
                ['soi' => $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_item')],
                'e.entity_id = soi.product_id'
            )
            ->group('e.entity_id')
            ->having('COUNT(soi.product_id) > ?', $reportCountVal);
```

Put into **$this->productCollectionFactory** product collection's factory auto generated magento 2 factory instance using automatic DI feature